# how do I use angular to convert, display and edit UTC time as browser local time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a simple example of displaying a date I get in UTC time. What I cannot figure out is how to display this in local time for the browser using angular. Also if it can be store in the scope.StartDateTime as UTC if it is changed, that would be cool. I am sure there is some sort of conversion method that I have not been able to find up to this point.

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="datetime" ng-model="StartDateTime">
</div>
```

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.StartDateTime = '2014-07-04T19:31:34';//starts with UTC time
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a format that can easily be parsed by the JS Date constructor, I recommend you first run that value through a Date object and then export (e.g. via .toString()).  The following example (done in NodeJS) illustrates my point:

`> (new Date("2014-07-04T19:31:34")).toString()
'Fri Jul 04 2014 14:31:34 GMT-0500 (CDT)'`

The Date object will handle localization for you, and accepts your UTC time without issue.  If you want your UTC time back out, use `.toISOString()`.

You might get what you're after simply by wrapping your variable assignation with a Date(...) constructor:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.StartDateTime = new Date('2014-07-04T19:31:34'); // starts with UTC time
}
```

Comment: I am hoping that angular will give me some 2 way binding tricks to keep it in utc but interact with the user in local time. Thanks for the input.